# How best to refactor variable instantiation duplication in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, coding-style, refactoring, code-duplication

I have two methods in Java that collect different information, but they both set up and run the same process which we then collect information from - and the collection of the data happens inside a loop, and the variables we instantiate are also used in the loop.

```
 Map<Integer, Integer> getResponsesWithCount(int baseCostMultiplier, int reels, int visibleSymbols, String stakeCostUuid, int totalBets) throws InsufficientFundsException {
    final int stake = getStake(baseCostMultiplier, stakeCostUuid);
    long balance = 10L * stake;
    final TestGpasPlatform testGpasPlatform = TestGpasPlatform.create(ryotaAdapter, TestGpasPlatform.DEFAULT_MIN_BET, Math.max(stake, TestGpasPlatform.DEFAULT_MAX_BET), TestGpasPlatform.DEFAULT_MAX_WIN, ImmutableList.of(baseCostMultiplier));

    final Map<Integer, Integer> responseCounts = new HashMap<>();
    for (int count = 0; count < totalBets; count++) {
        final Tuple2<List<Output>, TestGpasPlatform> result = playWithRealRng(baseCostMultiplier, count, reels, visibleSymbols, stakeCostUuid, testGpasPlatform);
        // If we run out of balance, re-start, we want to do meaningful spins that trigger features, etc
        balance = checkBalance(stake, balance, result._1(), count);
        final int byteLength = result._2.getLastResponse().map(s -> s.getBytes().length).orElse(0);
        responseCounts.putIfAbsent(byteLength, 0);
        responseCounts.put(byteLength, responseCounts.get(byteLength) + 1);
    }
    return responseCounts;
}

Map<Integer, Integer> getResponsesWithPayouts(int baseCostMultiplier, int reels, int visibleSymbols, String stakeCostUuid, int totalBets) throws InsufficientFundsException{
    final int stake = getStake(baseCostMultiplier, stakeCostUuid);
    long balance = 10L * stake;
    final TestGpasPlatform testGpasPlatform = TestGpasPlatform.create(ryotaAdapter, TestGpasPlatform.DEFAULT_MIN_BET, Math.max(stake, TestGpasPlatform.DEFAULT_MAX_BET), TestGpasPlatform.DEFAULT_MAX_WIN, ImmutableList.of(baseCostMultiplier));
    final Map<Integer, Integer> responseCounts = new HashMap<>();
    for (int count = 0; count < totalBets; count++) {
        final Tuple2<List<Output>, TestGpasPlatform> result = playWithRealRng(baseCostMultiplier, count, reels, visibleSymbols, stakeCostUuid, testGpasPlatform);

        // If we run out of balance, re-start, we want to do meaningful spins that trigger features, etc
        balance = checkBalance(stake, balance, result._1(), count);

        final int byteLength = result._2.getLastResponse().map(s -> s.getBytes().length).orElse(0);
        final PlayData playData = result._2.getLastResponse().map(s -> new Gson().fromJson(s, GdkPlayData.class)).orElse(new GdkPlayData());
        final java.util.List<SlotsActionData> actionData = playData.findLastPlay().getLastPlayInModeData().getSlotsData().getActions();
        final int sumOfPayouts = actionData.stream()
                                           .map(SlotsActionData::getPayouts)
                                           .mapToInt(java.util.List::size)
                                           .sum();
        responseCounts.putIfAbsent(byteLength, sumOfPayouts);
    }
    return responseCounts;
}
```

The first 6 lines of code of each of these methods are totally duplicated, but I'm not sure how I should or can clean this up.

I think an extension of this problem is that I have two chains of method calls which do the same thing for all but the data that is collected, and instead of having a boolean operator to split this functionality as I thought that was bad design, I implemented a new chain of methods to get it done. Should I have done this differently?

Comment: Select duplicated code part and use extract to method shortcut based on your IDE.

Comment: It does not work for the specific selected block. As I said in my post, the fact it begins before a loop and ends within a loop make it difficult to refactor. IDEA simply doesn't offer a solution.

Comment: Maybe I could create an object to hold the variables in the opening 4 lines of each method and use that object in each method rather than instantiating the 4 variables twice?

Comment: You can create a method that does all this stuff, and accepts a *consumer* of whatever it sets up and the `responseCounts`. Then you call that method with a lambda of the stuff you do inside.

Comment: Thanks RealSkeptic, could you elaborate a little bit or point me towards an example? My Java 8 isn't the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one common method and pass type like `withCount` as below,

```
Map<Integer, Integer> getResponses(int baseCostMultiplier, int reels, int visibleSymbols, String stakeCostUuid, int totalBets, boolean withCount) throws InsufficientFundsException {
    final int stake = getStake(baseCostMultiplier, stakeCostUuid);
    long balance = 10L * stake;
    final TestGpasPlatform testGpasPlatform = TestGpasPlatform.create(ryotaAdapter, TestGpasPlatform.DEFAULT_MIN_BET, Math.max(stake, TestGpasPlatform.DEFAULT_MAX_BET), TestGpasPlatform.DEFAULT_MAX_WIN, ImmutableList.of(baseCostMultiplier));

    final Map<Integer, Integer> responseCounts = new HashMap<>();
    for (int count = 0; count < totalBets; count++) {
        final Tuple2<List<Output>, TestGpasPlatform> result = playWithRealRng(baseCostMultiplier, count, reels, visibleSymbols, stakeCostUuid, testGpasPlatform);
        // If we run out of balance, re-start, we want to do meaningful spins that trigger features, etc
        balance = checkBalance(stake, balance, result._1(), count);
        final int byteLength = result._2.getLastResponse().map(s -> s.getBytes().length).orElse(0);

        if(withCount) {
            responseCounts.putIfAbsent(byteLength, 0);
            responseCounts.put(byteLength, responseCounts.get(byteLength) + 1);
        }else{
            final PlayData playData = result._2.getLastResponse().map(s -> new Gson().fromJson(s, GdkPlayData.class)).orElse(new GdkPlayData());
            final java.util.List<SlotsActionData> actionData = playData.findLastPlay().getLastPlayInModeData().getSlotsData().getActions();
            final int sumOfPayouts = actionData.stream()
                    .map(SlotsActionData::getPayouts)
                    .mapToInt(java.util.List::size)
                    .sum();
            responseCounts.putIfAbsent(byteLength, sumOfPayouts);
        }
    }
    return responseCounts;
}
```